# Bash Script Regular Expression Issue

Tags: regex, bash

I've got the following code and have looked at numerous examples but cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know the regular expression works (see https://regex101.com/r/cB9hN1/1) - just not in my bash script. It's for a git update hook, but clearly I'm doing something wrong! Here's what I've got:

```
regex='ref:( |)([D]|[U])([E]|[S])(\d+)';
string="My commit ref: US2233556"

if [[ $string =~ $regex ]];
  then
    echo "[SUCCESS] Your message contains ref: for a Story or Defect."
    exit 0
else
    echo "[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly. Please include a \"ref: USXXXXX\" or \"ref: DEXXX\" in the commit message."
    exit 1
fi
```

I'd appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Use `regex='ref:( |)([DU])([ES])([0-9]+)';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` and you can merge alternated character classes into single classes (`[D]|[U]` = `[DU]`):

```
regex='ref:( |)([DU])([ES])([0-9]+)';
```

See [demo here](https://ideone.com/3rc2eu)

If you are not using capture groups, just remove them:

```
regex='ref: ?[DU][ES][0-9]+';
```

Here is [another demo](https://ideone.com/FJoOVw). Note that `( |)` can be written shorter as `( ?)` or `( )?` and this way it will cause less backtracking.

Comment: Seriously, that \d+ was my main problem?!

Comment: Yes, it was the main problem. Bash does not support the PCRE regex flavor, it is much poorer.

Comment: Oh dear! Thank you! Will accept the answer as soon as I'm allowed to!